# Why objective function is always linear in semidefinite programing?

Tags: semidefinite-programming

Almost all the semidefinite programming paper I found has a linear objective function, which is $\mbox{tr}(CX)$. Why?

---

For example, in [this paper](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-251j-introduction-to-mathematical-programming-fall-2009/readings/MIT6_251JF09_SDP.pdf) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming#Equivalent_formulations), the objective function is always $\mbox{tr}(CX)$, where $C$ is a known matrix. The goal is to minimize $\mbox{tr}(CX)$, such that $X\succeq0$ and satisfy some linear constraints. I wonder what is the difficulty to generalize the objective function $\mbox{tr}(CX)$ to general cases, e.g. convex functions? Such as strictly convex smooth objective function $\ell(X)=\mbox{tr}(CXX)$, where $C\succ0$? Or $\ell(X)=\mbox{tr}(CXX) -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(X_{ii})$?

Comment: That is just how it is defined. However, all (single) objective optimisation problems can be expressed as a constrained problem with a linear objective.

Comment: I am confused why it has to be defined this way. Can you please elaborate more on "all (single) objective optimisation problems can be expressed as a constrained problem with a linear objective"? For example, if we would like to minimize negative log likelihood of gaussian with precision matrix as parameter, I am not sure how it would be expressed as a linear objective functioin.

Comment: $\min \{ f(x) | x \in D \} $ is equivalent to $\min \{ t | f(x) \le t, x \in D\}$. It is not saying much really.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: All linear functions on real symmetric matrices can be expressed as a trace. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear. It looks people only use $\mbox{tr}(CX)$ as objective in SPD. Why not objective function $l(X) = \mbox{tr}(CXX^T)$, or $l(X) = \mbox{tr}(CXX^T) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(X_{ii})$, or other strictly convex function? Here let's say $C\succ0$.

Comment: It is a good question, I suppose it is partly answered by the fact I mentioned above (the equivalent problem) and partly that it is not fashionable. I have found that it is often better to solve the original problem rather that the reformulated one, but often requires more analysis.

Comment: Basically what @copper.hat said: if you allowed arbitrary objectives, the problem would be as complex as general convex programming